# HTML Service - PWA

Tags: google-apps-script, progressive-web-apps

Sorry for a noob question - as I've just started with web development half a year ago..

I need your help regarding setting my GAS app into a PWA. Is there such a possibility? I struggle to find any really helpful resources on how to create a service workers and manifest files to work correctly. It'd be extremely helpful for me to get trained on the topic.

Thanks.

Comment: Google Apps Script is not persistent server-side.

Comment: @tehhowch could you specify? I'm quite new to the topic and if you could at least provide some docs or tuts It would help me very much. Is there any possibility to overcome limitations to change GAS web app to the PWA? Thanks!

Comment: This is not a "find me tutorials" website. I'm merely commenting that there is no persistence of memory between calls to apps script - each hit to a webapp will spool a new instance.

Comment: @tehhowch Got it! I've noticed there is no memory in GAS. My idea would be to capture the main index.html file and save it as offline-mode version.

If that's not possible, a non-offline version of the app would be okay - just simply to make it load in a separate instance (not in browser window) and add an icon to Android homescreen (not a shortcut to website).

Answer (score 0):

Having a valid manifest.json will enable your application to add to home screen of Android, iOS - Safari only, Chrome - All desktop OS.

You can use [this link](https://app-manifest.firebaseapp.com/) to generate manifest.json for your application and keep in the root of your project and link it using index.html like below,

You can use [Workbox](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/get-started) to generate service worker for your application.

Comment: Thanks! The problem is I'm not sure how to put any file to the "root" of the page, as Google Apps Script HTML Service is not really allowing to view the server content.

Comment: I’m not familiar with google apps scripts. You can place the manifest in non root folder as well. Just link it to the right path in index.html or what ever your home page is.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your GAS app is but if it is based on HTML/JS/CSS you can try www.pwabuilder.com for this purpose. It will give you the manifest and the service worker to put in your code.

You can also try the Lighthouse extension in Chrome and activate it when you are on your site. It will tell you if you app is PWA compatible and what needs work.